# convert JSON datetime 2017-03-19T23:54:46 to 3/19/2017 11:54:46 PM

Tags: c#, json, datetime, ssis, etl

How to do this in script `C#` script of **SSIS**.Currently the datetime is a string from `JSON` column.I am trying to do

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

but error says the `CreationTime` is not in current context.I tried inside all sections like

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
```

And

```
public override void PostExecute()
```

but still get the same error.

Comment: You are asking about c# code, why did you tag ssis, etl and sql server instead of c#?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DateTime.ParseExact()` Function

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",provider);
```

If you need to return it as String with the following format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` you can use the `ToString()` function

```
String strDate = convertedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

**Reference**

- [DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)